# Mocha/Jasmine: Using describe and it correctly ? Standard pattern available?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js, jestjs

I was wondering if there is some standard pattern to be able to use describe and it correctly. I am testing a node application so my tests are stored under a directory called tests in the root.

I was trying to understand how to use describe. My first thought is to use class names and method names as describe and then different test situations for the method using it. I suppose something like this.

```
 describe ('Calculation Class')
      describe ('getSquaredArea()')
         it('should return correct value if passed a valid numeric')
                /* one situation */

         it('should return null when the value passed is not a numeric) 
               /* another situation /*
```

Is this recommended using the method name, understanding that in the calculation class will be a number of different methods?

I suppose my question refers to either mocha or jasmine or jest.

I was also thinking about testing the front end and I was thinking about using the same pattern above but removing the first describe as the tests will be stored with the file they are testing and not separately in the test root directory.

I am not sure about the second describe above, just playing the method name there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mocha test should look like this.

```
var testObj;
describe ('#User', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        //init what the object contains
        testObj = new DataStore(data, Container);
    });
    describe ('Admin', function () {
     //other tests
    });

    it ('#Should return the name of the user', function () {
        assert.equal(testObj.get('user'), dummyData.user);
    });

    it("should offer simple HTTP request capabilities", function () {
        return chakram.get("http://httpbin.org/get");
    });
});
```